# Setting up a gazebo Application using RenderEngine and GUIOverlay in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am creating a game that uses gazebo simulator. I need help on how to set up an application and rendering scene using RenderEngine.hh, I would like to use Ogre3d functionality to render and set up the camera and GUIOverlay class for the GUI.

I haven't found any tutorials of how I could use these two classes and I am stuck.
Could anyone please provide examples of how you would go about using RenderEngine.hh to render your scene from gazebo.
What steps are involved to achieve this?Please take me from file creation, to cmake files if needed.
The end result of this should be an App.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1393/setting-up-a-gazebo-application--using-renderengine-and-guioverlay-in-gazebo/) by [iamhero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/215/iamhero/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately there are no tutorials on using the Gazebo rendering library and gui library in a separate application. Right now, you'd be best served by looking at the code. Check out `gazebo/gui/GLWidget.cc` to see how QT interfaces with OGRE. This will give you a good starting point.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0